# C# Decrypting AES/ECB Paddded Using PKCS#5

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm making a small application for fun in C# which retrieves a image from a server which is encrypted using AES/ECB with a single synchronous key (which I know) and padded using PKCS#5.

I tried just downloading the image by using a BinaryReader, however when I go to open the image, it is a corrupt file. I assume this is because it is encrypted. Here is my code:

```
string repsonseData = string.Empty;
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()){
   using (var reader = new BinaryReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
     Byte[] lnByte = reader.ReadBytes(1 * 1024 * 1024 * 10);
      using (FileStream lxFS = new FileStream("imageName.jpg", FileMode.Create)) {
         lxFS.Write(lnByte, 0, lnByte.Length);
      }
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Never use ECB. It is completely insecure.

Comment: @Jeff The file that I retrieve is encrypted in that, which is out of my control, as it is not my service. I just need to decrypt it.

Comment: Can you post the decrypt code?

Comment: @jlvaquero The key? M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4

Comment: I mean the source code you use to decrypt the byte array you downloaded. Show us what are you tried.

Comment: @jlvaquero That's the problem, I haven't tried anything. I know very little about encryption/decryption to do so. The furthest I have gone with that is encrypting plain text into MD5 ;).

Comment: Well... If you google ".NET AES Decryption example" you'll get a lot of info. Try to understand it and write some code before ask please.